# Service Stack Plug-in Not Addressable

Tags: servicestack

I am trying to setup a modular ServiceStack implementation but I can't seem to figure out how to address my plug-in.

Here is my ASP.Net MVC 4 Global.asax.cs:

```
 public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    [Route("/heartbeat")]
    public class HeartBeat
    {
    }

    public class HeartBeatResponse
    {
        public bool IsAlive { get; set; }
    }

    public class ApiService : Service
    {
        public object Any(HeartBeat request)
        {
            var settings = new AppSettings();

            return new HeartBeatResponse { IsAlive = true };
        }
    }
    public class AppHost : AppHostBase
    {
        public AppHost() : base("Api Services", typeof(ApiService).Assembly) { }

        public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
        {
            Plugins.Add(new ValidationFeature());
            Plugins.Add(new StoreServices());
        }
    }
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        new AppHost().Init();
    }
```

This loads fine and I'm able to see the available "HeartBeat" Service.  The service loaded by the plug-in is not found though.

Here is the plug-in code:

```
public class StoreServices: IPlugin
{
    private IAppHost _appHost;

    public void Register(IAppHost appHost)
    {
        if(null==appHost)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("appHost");

        _appHost = appHost;
        _appHost.RegisterService<StoreService>("/stores");
    }
}
```

and the corresponding service that it loads:

```
 public class StoreService:Service
{
    public Messages.StoreResponse Get(Messages.Store request)
    {
        var store = new Messages.Store {Name = "My Store", City = "Somewhere In", State = "NY"};
        return new Messages.StoreResponse {Store = store};
    }
}


[Route("/{State}/{City}/{Name*}")]
[Route("/{id}")]
public class Store : IReturn<StoreResponse>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
}

public class StoreResponse
{
    public Store Store { get; set; }
}
```

The url to run heartbeat is from localhost}/heartbeat and the meta can be found at from localhost}/metadata.

When I try to call {from localhost}/stores/1234 though I get a unresolved route?, but if you see the route attribute on the service call it should resolve?

The following is the response I get for the stores request:

```
Handler for Request not found: 


Request.ApplicationPath: /
Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath: /stores/123
Request.FilePath: /stores/123
Request.HttpMethod: GET
Request.MapPath('~'): C:\Source Code\White Rabbit\SpiritShop\SpiritShop.Api\
Request.Path: /stores/123
Request.PathInfo: 
Request.ResolvedPathInfo: /stores/123
Request.PhysicalPath: C:\Source Code\White Rabbit\SpiritShop\SpiritShop.Api\stores\123
Request.PhysicalApplicationPath: C:\Source Code\White Rabbit\SpiritShop\SpiritShop.Api\
Request.QueryString: 
Request.RawUrl: /stores/123
Request.Url.AbsoluteUri: http://localhost:55810/stores/123
Request.Url.AbsolutePath: /stores/123
Request.Url.Fragment: 
Request.Url.Host: localhost
Request.Url.LocalPath: /stores/123
Request.Url.Port: 55810
Request.Url.Query: 
Request.Url.Scheme: http
Request.Url.Segments: System.String[]
App.IsIntegratedPipeline: True
App.WebHostPhysicalPath: C:\Source Code\White Rabbit\SpiritShop\SpiritShop.Api
App.WebHostRootFileNames: [global.asax,global.asax.cs,packages.config,spiritshop.api.csproj,spiritshop.api.csproj.user,spiritshop.api.csproj.vspscc,web.config,web.debug.config,web.release.config,api,app_data,bin,obj,properties]
App.DefaultHandler: metadata
App.DebugLastHandlerArgs: GET|/stores/123|C:\Source Code\White Rabbit\SpiritShop\SpiritShop.Api\stores\123
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code doesn't does not give your service a url prefix like you're assuming:

```
_appHost.RegisterService<StoreService>("/stores");
```

Instead the optional `params string[] atRestPaths` only specifies routes for the **DefaultRequest** route of that Service. You can specify which operation is the default using the `[DeafultRequest]` attribute, e.g:

```
[DefaultRequest(typeof(Store))]
public class StoreService : Service { ... }
```

Which allows you to specify the routes in-line instead of on the request DTO, i.e:

```
_appHost.RegisterService<StoreService>(
   "/stores/{State}/{City}/{Name*}",
   "/stores/{Id}");
```

But as you've already got the routes on the Request DTO you can ignore them here, i.e:

```
_appHost.RegisterService<StoreService>();
```

But you'll need to include the missing `/stores` url prefix, e.g:

```
[Route("/stores/{State}/{City}/{Name*}")]
[Route("/stores/{Id}")]
public class Store : IReturn<StoreResponse> { .. }
```